# problems fetching a simple JSON data via getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

im getting crazy over this. doenst seem to work after a following a tutorial very closely.

can you please take a look at my code. i just want to print a `JSON` data at my `<ul>` element

my index page

```
...
<body>
  <ul>
  </ul>
<div id="foo">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
...
```

my custom.js

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $.getJSON("json_data.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.emp, function() {
            $("ul").append("<li>test:" + this['name'] + "</li><li>" + this['last'] + "</li>");
        });
    });
});
```

my json_data.json

```
{
    "emp": [
        { "name" : "bob", "last": "marley" },
        { "name" : "kurt", "last": "cobain" }
    ]
}
```

what am i missing here? checking at my chrome developers tools > Network
i get status for `jquery.js` and `custom.js` **304 not modified**

i dont know if this affects why my fetching JSON wont work.

Comment: How does the response look? console.log(data) in getJson callback and ckeck in console.

Comment: Try giving the CDN link for jquery from the examples they have provided on their site.

Comment: @Jite nothing appears in my console, i placed it after my `$.getJSON("json_data.json", function(data) {`

Comment: @user1848739 tried that aswell, im sure that my jquery works. ive tried some tests over it.

Comment: Try set a console.log("Test") or similar in the document ready callback, just to see that jquery actualy get loaded.

Comment: @Jite no console logs appears. but thats weird. my links to my `JS` seems to be fine, when i try to access them via devtool > elements and clicked on the URL of my js, i get redirected to them, they appear to be correct.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zBg4G/ check this fiddle

Comment: Fiddled it as well... Your each seems fine.  I suspect your data is cached and empty/old in the cache.  http://jsfiddle.net/YbnxR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the fiddle provided in the comment.

```
var jsonString = {"emp": [{ "name": "bob", "last": "marley" },{ "name": "kurt", "last": "cobain" }]};

    $.each(jsonString.emp, function (key, value) {
        alert(jsonString.emp[key]["name"] + jsonString.emp[key]["last"]);
         $("ul").append("<li>" + jsonString.emp[key]["name"] + " " + jsonString.emp[key]["last"] + "</li>");
        console.log(key, value);

    });
```

It seems you need the key and value. Key is the index and value is respected value for object. I hope it works for you.

Comment: His $.each seems fine...  I suspect the cache is in the way.

Comment: thank you, adding the `(key, value)` seems to solve my problem. thank you so much. but id like to ask also, why in the youtube tutorial his code seems to work without the `(key,value)`? but mine requires?